# How to connect to a virtual server using TightVNC from a Windows XP machine?

Tags: 11.10, server, remote-desktop, vnc

Our client from a different country provided us a VPN connection which we connect through Sonicwall net-extender. I am using Windows XP 32-bit.

After that I use `putty` to connect to the client's Ubuntu Linux server through SSH who have a static local IP 192.168.x.x and I get connected to the command line interface.

Then I installed TightVNC server from command line and run it, then I use TightVNC Viewer for Windows to connect to the Ubuntu desktop (GNOME) and I get connected.

**The problem:** Whenever i tried to use any application the TightVNC window gets suddenly closed before the application launches and sometimes it shows the message `Connection closed`. Only few applications work like package installer and some of settings, not even the desktop sharing option is working.

I want to configure MySQL database and web applications in that Ubuntu server, it's Ubuntu 11.10.

Can somebody guide me regarding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need tightvnc to use ubuntu: just putty:

- you are telling that you can conect to the ubuntu server via putty so that's ok.
- You can use mysql with comand line
- apache is also used with comand line

To have in mid: know that you can control apache and mysql to work this way (remember as root: `sudo -i`) `service <apache2ormysql> stop/start/restart/status`

**first install mysql as root.**

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install mysql
```

In the middle of the instalation a password for the root of mysql will be ask to you.

the you just login to your mysql:

```
:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 34
Server version: 5.1.58-1ubuntu1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to modify and redistribute it under the GPL v2 license

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

if you do sudo -i you whon't need to use the -u root part

```
 mysql -p
Enter password:
```

the to use mysql just read the manual:

1. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/mysql.1.html
2. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/

**To a web application use apache, and php**

```
sudo -i
apt-get install apache2
apt-get install php5
```

for now I will tell those two maybe you will need more things (like a conector to php-apache2 or stuff like these).

the configuration of php you will need to edit like root (`sudo -i`)

```
:~# vi /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

and all the apache2 config is in `/etc/apache2/`, and your site will be deplayed here `:/var/www`.
read the respective manual to do what you need.

also make firend of vi or nano... they are usefull

this lecture could be more helpful: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

> note: if you need more help or how to set it up... just
>   ask =D

Comment: Thanx for the help, it seems i have to use command line well thats fine. Can you tell me how can i install un-stable PEAR module? I installed my required PEAR modules but there is one that is unstable "NET_HL7" and unbuntu denies to install it because its version is unstable but i want to install it

Comment: take a look at this http://pear.php.net/package/Net_HL7

Comment: Well thanx, i got the answer `pear install Net_HL7-alpha` or `pear install Net_HL7-0.1.1` will install the unstable alpha version. Help get from [link](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.installing.php)